# An unexpected transaction removed money from my wallet

Tags: transactions, theft, exodus

I sent a transaction from Kraken to my wallet Exodus. All went smooth and the transaction was confirmed in my wallet yesterday around 12 AM.
This is the ID: fc933cc0456e8d8927ef1feb6392bf697279466e85d6f886a1637b09c7add45a

Suddenly one hour later I have 0 Bitcoin/EUR and a random transaction showing up.
I went in this website and saw that a transaction came up with this ID:

ba9aa12d2d28f4b786803e24a27722ceceaa1ec13349368cb93310f6deeeb632

I really have no idea what the hell happened.

Thank you for your time.

Kind regards,

Joanna

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't create the second transaction it means that one of the following probably applies:

- Someone else has, at some time in the past, known a previous or current password for your Exodus wallet.
- Someone has had access to your written down backup of your recovery phrase or private key.
- Your Exodus wallet is a fake wallet or has been compromised by some malicious add-on feature.
- Your computer or device has been infected with malware.

In any case, the money is gone and you won't be able to retrieve it.

It is certain you will be contacted by people claiming that they, or someone they know, can get your money back. Their intent is to trick you into giving them money using invented fake fees, fake charges or anything else they can dream up that they think you will fall for.